# setting up CORS with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

I have a welcome page in my website on Wordpress (that uses php) 
www.MYWEBSITE/welcome.html

I need to allow other websites to access the header.
So,I need to add something like

@header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.OTHERWEBSITE.com' );

Where do I add the header so that the OTHERWEBSITE can access MYWEBSITE's resources?

Expected OUTPUT:
If I use
   curl -I -L www.MYWEBSITE/welcome.html 
then I need to get the header info

I do not have a header.php page in the resources. Do i need to build one?
Where am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With FALSE as second parameters to no allowed overwriting headers

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.OTHERWEBSITE.com', false );
```

In general this allow somes domains to access to your ressources (API REST, SOAP, Webservices ...) all sites who need cross site scripting we can talk about google, youtube, twitter, but also private api's ... etc)

Comment: in which page do i use the header ?

Comment: Where you want to share ressources with others, who need to acces to :).

Comment: I just tried adding 
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.OTHERWEBSITE.com', false );
 
to the welcome.html page, and upon using curl command from my terminal, I did not get back any headers :( ...

Comment: try a simple file_get_content(URL); if you use GET in General an API allow GET POST DELETE  PUT ...

Comment: <?php @header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: MYOTHERWEBSITE.com';, false );
 @header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT"); 

@header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Custom-Header"); ?> 

<html> 

<head> <title> Welcome page </title> </head> 

<body> WELCOME ! </body> 
</html> 


This is the page. What else do I add? Sorry, a beginner at this.

Comment: However, when I curl from the terminal, I only get
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Sep 2017 23:25:24 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1224
Content-Type: text/html

     but not header values!

Comment: You should add your interface web as data from database but i guess you need to use a API but to create all at the begin is very long but you can. If you want to jump to lib download this https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api you can start and install it to test how is coded and how you can make your own used it.

Comment: Try after your header setcookie("TestCookie", "foobar"); or add a php Array as $myarray['success'] = "MaValue"; and do at the end a header('content-type application/json'); and an  echo json_encode($myarray); You got a response json with {'success':'MaValue'}

Comment: <?php
@header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://MYOTHERWEBSITE.com', false );
@header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
@header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Custom-Header");
header('content-type application/json');
echo json_encode($myarray); 

$myarray['success'] = "MyValue";

?>
<html> <head> <title> Welcome page </title> </head> <body> WELCOME ! </body> </html> 


       IS this the way? because I am not getting anything new from the command line. Or is the echo command misplaced?

@header or just header ?

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress, it has some internal permission management.
So, just to the .htaccess file,

header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.OTHERWEBSITE.com